# Call a MVC action method via ajax from an .aspx from another project in solution

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

How can I successfully call an action method via ajax from an .aspx from another project in solution ?

.aspx code below from Project1:

```
var url = 'http://local.myproject.co.uk/Test/Testing';
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: url,
            data: { cookieValue: "test" },
            cache: false,
            success: function (result) {
            }
        });
```

TestController from Project2 below:

```
public string Testing(string cookieValue)
{
    return cookieValue;
}
```

The above does not work.

How can I make it work?

Comment: The value you are returning and the method return type does not match!
Change the return type to `string` to start with. Also are you making a CROSS DOMAIN AJAX REQUEST ?

Comment: changed the method type to string, but the problem is that the ajax call does it does not reach to action method in controller

Comment: Are you making a CROSS DOMAIN AJAX REQUEST

Comment: I'm making a request from one project to another within the same solution in my local website

Comment: the projects have different domain names, yes

Answer (score 0):

> How can I successfully call an action method via ajax from an .aspx
>   from another project in solution ?

You have to use the correct port in order to query your other project.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set up ***CORS*** in MVC Middleware pipeline in order for ASPX site to access MVC site.

[Setting up CORS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors#setting-up-cors)

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, 
    ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
   ...

    // Shows UseCors with CorsPolicyBuilder.
    app.UseCors(builder => builder.WithOrigins("http://example.com"));

   ...
}
```